# multiple table entries in loopback4

Tags: loopback4

I want to insert multiple records in mysql with loopback4.
e.g. I have a table called Orders I want to insert an entry in orders table and from that entry I want to find order_id and from that order_id I want to insert multiple products in Order_Products table.
How can this be done via loopback4?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CreateAll` ;
Example:

```
const order:Orders = await this.orderRepository.create(oreder);
let products=products.map((pro:any)=>{
return{
    ...pro,
    order_id:order.id
}
})  
const product = await this.productRepository.createAll(products);
```